# How to select a node whose subelement includes some text in Python?

Tags: python, lxml

I have an xml file like this:

```
<data>
      <entry>
           <word>ABC</word> (this)
      </entry>
      <entry>
           <word>ABC</word> [not this]
      </entry>
</data>
```

I want to select  nodes whose descendant include "(", and move (.*) to the text of `<entry>`. That is:

```
<data>
      <entry>
           (this)
           <word>ABC</word>
      </entry>
      <entry>
           <word>ABC</word> [not this]
      </entry>
</data>
```

I'm using lxml. And I tried:

```
 import lxml.etree as ET
 data = ET.parse('sample.xml')
 for entry in data.iter('entry'):
      A = entry.xpath('.//*[text() = ".*(.*?)"]')
```

But it doesn't work. "(" can appear as a tail of a node or as a text of a node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

First, you're trying to use xpath to do regex matching, but you're using =.  Your regex is also improperly formatted.  To actually do regex matching in xpath, you'd need to do something like:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
data = ET.parse('sample.xml')
regexpNS = "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
for entry in data.iter('entry'):
    A = entry.xpath('.//*[re:test(text(), ".*\(.*\).*")]',
                    namespaces={'re':regexpNS})
```

Unfortunately, this won't actually work for you because you want text in the tail, which isn't included in `text()`.  The lxml docs make it look like this should be included in `string()`, but I tried that and it doesn't work either.  I can't find any way to do this using xpath and lxml.

So, here's a way to do it with more Python and less xpath:

```
 import re
 import lxml.etree as ET
 rx = re.compile('.*\(.*\).*')
 data = ET.parse('sample.xml')
 for entry in data.iter('entry'):
    for child in entry.xpath('.//*'):
        if rx.match(child.text + child.tail):
            # Your manipulations go here
            print child
```

In either case, a happy side effect is that this regex is having a totally rockin' good time in the snow: `.*\(.*\).*`.

Answer (score 0):

if `(` in tail and move it to parent's text..  then.. .

```
In [67]: myxml="""<data>
    ...:       <entry>
    ...:            <word>ABC</word> (this)
    ...:       </entry>
    ...:       <entry>
    ...:            <word>ABC</word> [not this]
    ...:       </entry>
    ...: </data>"""

In [68]: import StringIO, re, lxml.etree as ET

In [69]: f=StringIO.StringIO(myxml)

In [70]: data=ET.parse(f)

In [71]: print ET.tostring(data)
<data>
      <entry>
           <word>ABC</word> (this)
      </entry>
      <entry>
           <word>ABC</word> [not this]
      </entry>
</data>

In [72]: for elem in data.findall("/entry/"):
    ...:     if re.match(".*\(.*\).*",elem.tail):
    ...:         elem.getparent().text=elem.tail
    ...:         elem.tail=None
    ...:         

In [73]: print ET.tostring(data)
<data>
      <entry> (this)
      <word>ABC</word></entry>
      <entry>
           <word>ABC</word> [not this]
      </entry>
</data>
```